# binding Strings of an Obect in a List <> to ListView in xaml with Data Templating

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, listview

Okay so in wpf xaml markup the data binding features allow for data binding a list to a listView. To do I specified the DataContext and set the ItemSource to the DataContext. This works and the listView is populated with the items. The items though are objects and to be able to have the displayed item in the list view as a string property of get set implementation from the object enumerated in the list view I am attempting to use an Item Template. Though this is not working and I'm uncertain why.

How exactly does Item Template and the Data Binding function in this scenario? And what would be workable solutions to this problem? Is there a way to specify the property in the text box as being local to the enumerated objects. Please Help I've honestly been working on this for a while and research hasn't provided the answers.

ItemList is a list of objects. ItemName is a string property of ItemList. The ItemSource and DataContext works but the textblock does not.

Preferably a solution using only xaml.

```
<ListView DataContext="this.ItemList" ItemsSource="{Binding }" Name ="Items">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" >
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Come on , you could have spent less time searching for this than writing your question http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview). As a note, `DataContext="this.ItemList"` makes no sense in XAML. The DataContext should perhaps also better be set at the Window level, to the object that declares the ItemList property (e.g. `DataContext = this` in the Window constructor). Then the ItemsSource Binding would be `ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}"`. That said, the fact that ItemName isn't shown indicates that it is not a public property of the item class.

Answer (score 0):

Except for some unconventional ways of working pointed out by Clemens, I think the only actual error you make is the fact that ItemName is a property of ItemList instead of the enumerated objects' class.

You ask "Is there a way to specify the property in the text box as being local to the enumerated objects". Well, this is the actual case: the TextBlock's datacontext IS the enumerated object. More precisely: all bindings in the itemtemplate will go look in the enumerated object unless the binding explicitly tells otherwise. So, if your enumerated object has eg. a string property ObjectName, its value will definitely get bound and shown by the textblock.